# How to remove border around images?

Tags: html, css

I'm a mobile developer struggling with some HTML works in my app. It looks too easy but I couldn't figure it out:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/iwsyih.gif"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

a white border around image appears but I don't want that happen. how to remove it? thanks

Comment: thanks anyone for your kind help +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the default padding/margin on the `body` element. That's the purpose of a 'CSS reset'. Just add this to your styles:

```
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Comment: Can you tell me more about CSS reset?

Comment: Check this out: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 2):

try this code please

```
img{
   border:0;
}
```

You can also add a class for only this image:

```
img.img{
  order:0;
}

<img src="http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/iwsyih.gif" class="img"/>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UpGh2/)

By default the setting of border is `medium none color`

Comment: where does `.myClass` comes from? It should be `.img`

Comment: PS your CSS ".myClass" example doesn't match your HTML.

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri still wrong. You mean `img.img`. Also without using CSS it don't display any white border in fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/iwsyih.gif" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;border:0px"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<img src="http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/iwsyih.gif" style="border:0px;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using css attachment, then:

```
    img{
   border:0;
}
```

If you are using styles in the div itself, then use `style="border:0px"`