# How to remove automatically generated HTML container margin around image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to remove the automatically generated container margin around this image. Below is the code I used to produce it. You can view the website [here](https://jamesharnett.github.io/SA-website/vice-presidents.html). I tried to add a [margin and padding item to the body element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028074/how-to-remove-border-around-images), but it didn't resolve the issue.

[image]

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.85;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="./img/headshots/Exec_DMoon.jpg" width="240" height="240" alt="Photo of David Moon, Assistant Vice President for Financial Affairs" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text"><b>David Moon</b> Assistant Vice President for Financial Affairs, <a class="usa-external_link" target="_blank" href="mailto:davidmoon826@gwmail.gwu.edu">Email</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is the desired output**:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Am I missing something? The site you linked to looks like the "desired output". Also the code on your site doesn't match the screenshot of your code

Comment: Give [flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) a go, will save you some headaches.

Comment: @j08691 Sorry, I just synced my code to the Github page, now it shows as I described.

Comment: It would be easier to answer this question if your snippet actually represented the code you'd like to use. For instance, having more than one image, and using images that are able to be referenced. You can use a service like lorempixel.com to get images that are the same size as yours, if you don't want to point to the full URL of your own images in the snippet.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The code for this page can be viewed here: https://github.com/jamesharnett/SA-website/blob/master/vice-presidents.html

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The link to the GitHub page is https://jamesharnett.github.io/SA-website/vice-presidents.html

Comment: And, as we've seen, that code changes. When you change that code again, what good will this question do for anyone else? Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from *Johannes* almost worked, but it caused issues where text would reposition itself into the open gaps (see image below), instead of formatting below all the images.

[image]

**The solution was to use `display: inline-block;` in `.container`**, as *Adrian* recommended.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fade in Overlay</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Fade in Overlay</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix for this, imo: wrap the items you want in a grid in a div and give the div `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well, just add `float: left` to `.container`

(to achieve what you show under "this is the desired output")

Comment: Float will cause other issues, though, which will need to be mitigated. `display: inline-block` is generally easier to work with and doesn't require clear fixing.

Comment: In this particular case (when you add it at the original page) float works perfectly.